# Move Method for Mocking?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I have unit tests that calls `ApplicationShouldBeInstalled(app)` to make sure it's working correctly. The actual production code, below, also calls that method, so it doesn't accidentally install an app. However, nothing is preventing a developer from removing that line of code where the check is done. And my unit tests wouldn't catch that because the tests are testing the `ApplicationShouldBeInstalled(app)` method, and not the `InstallApplications()` method.

I can't call `InstallApplications()` from my test code because then it would attempt to install an application. `InstallApplication(app)` is a method in the same class, not another class where I can mock it with an interface. Is there a way to make sure InstallApplications() always performs that check? I guess I could move `ApplicationShouldBeInstalled(app)` to another class and mock it, but then I'm moving code just for the sake of testing/mocking. Is there a better way?

```
public void InstallApplications()
{
    foreach (App app in this._apps)
    {
        if (!ApplicationShouldBeInstalled(app)) { continue; }

        InstallApplication(app);
    }                       
}
```

The mocking option would look like this. The `Container` would return the real implementation when running live, and a mock when running the test.

```
public void InstallApplications()
{
    foreach (App app in this._apps)
    {
        if (!ApplicationShouldBeInstalled(app)) { continue; }

        Container.Resolve<IInstaller>().InstallApplication(app);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Can you extract an interface from the method and then mock the interface?

Comment: For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that was the option I listed in my question. So, yeah, I could, but I'm wondering if there is a better way. IMO, all of that code belongs in the class in which it currently resides. I will move it though, if that's what I have to do to be able to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, remove the code that controls the policy of whether or not the application should be installed from the code that handles the installation. This will allow you to test both pieces of code in isolation and gain confidence that each is doing what you require. I would even go so far as to have 3 collaborators here. The code that controls the loop, the code that controls validating against the policy, and finally the code that performs the install. Three pieces, independently testable, easier to verify.

```
foreach (var app in this._apps)
{
     if (!applicationInstallationPolicyProvider.CanInstall(app)) // can be mocked away
     {
          continue;
     }

     applicationInstaller.Install(app); // can also be mocked away
}
```

I think the key for you is when you said in the question "you cannot run the install code in test." But it should be important for you to verify that the loop actually *will* call the installation code when required. That should be enough motivation already to try to isolate it, whether or not you take to the degree that I might prefer.

Comment: This fits with what I just added to my question, so I believe I was on the right path. Thanks!

Comment: I think the key for you is when you said in the question "you cannot run the install code in test." But it should be important for you to verify that the loop actually *will* call the installation code! That should be enough motivation already to try to isolate it.

Comment: Agreed! Doing it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you extract it to an interface your not really removing code that belongs in the class. You are requiring the class to implement the members. A major benefit to using interfaces is that it allows you to mock them so that you do not actually change functionality. You mock the interface then you verify that a specific method is actually doing what you expect it to do.

On a side note it also allows you to use dependency injection so that your not creating instances of objects in memory constantly.